# How can I read a txt file with custom path, but "universal" path for any computer users?

Tags: path, filereader, streamreader

I would like to read a text file(.txt) without using `bin/debug` folder, because I have to push the project into github, and I need a path for my text file(.txt) which one is a folder in the solution. The path format must works for any computer, full path from my computer is not good.

```
using (System.IO.StreamReader srr = new System.IO.StreamReader(@"C:\example\example\example\example\example\example\FolderInSolution\highscoreFile.txt"))
displayHighScore.Content = srr.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

I see two options for you, namely:

1. Use a relative path and place your file directly in the root folder, for example:

```bash
.
├── dotnet.csproj
├── highscoreFile.txt
└── Program.cs
```

Then you could remove most of that file path:

```cs
using (System.IO.StreamReader srr = new System.IO.StreamReader(@"highscoreFile.txt")) {
    Console.WriteLine(srr.ReadLine());
}
```

2. Use an environment variable that each user could use to indicate where your file is:

```cs
string path = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("HIGH_SCORE_FILE")
using (System.IO.StreamReader srr = new System.IO.StreamReader(path)) {
    Console.WriteLine(srr.ReadLine());
}
```